# Puppet 3.0.0 error: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections [:main, :agent, :ssl]

Tags: puppet

After upgrading a node to Puppet 3.0.0 from the Puppet Labs YUM repository, the node that gets upgraded throws a munging error:

```
[ashinn@dis1 ~]$ sudo puppet agent --test --trace
Error: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections [:main, :agent, :ssl]: Parameter path failed on File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Munging failed for value "/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs" in class path: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileCollection
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.19/lib/puppet/type/file.rb:62:in unsafe_munge'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parameter.rb:209:inmunge'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parameter.rb:252:in value='
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:414:in[]='
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:1660:in set_name'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:1647:ininitialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.19/lib/puppet/type/file.rb:434:in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource.rb:290:innew'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource.rb:290:in to_ral'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:570:insend'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:570:in to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:551:ineach'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:551:in to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:475:into_ral'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:891:in use'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:230:insynchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:885:in use'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:450:insetup'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:438:inplugin_hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb:500:inexit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:76:inexecute'
/usr/bin/puppet:10
Error: Could not prepare for execution: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections [:main, :agent, :ssl]: Parameter path failed on File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Munging failed for value "/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs" in class path: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileCollection
Parameter path failed on File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Munging failed for value "/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs" in class path: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileCollection
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.19/lib/puppet/type/file.rb:62:in unsafe_munge'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parameter.rb:209:inmunge'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parameter.rb:252:in value='
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:414:in[]='
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:1660:in set_name'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type.rb:1647:ininitialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.19/lib/puppet/type/file.rb:434:in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource.rb:290:innew'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource.rb:290:in to_ral'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:570:insend'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:570:in to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:551:ineach'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:551:in to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:475:into_ral'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:891:in use'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:230:insynchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:885:in use'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:450:insetup'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:438:inplugin_hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb:500:inexit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:344:in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:76:inexecute'
/usr/bin/puppet:10
```

I noticed that the file reported (in this error `/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs`) changes every time I try. It seems to always be a random file in /var/lib/puppet. Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are picking up a 2.7.19 gem alongside the RPM -- does 'sudo gem list' show a Puppet gem installed?

The root cause of this is a feature where puppet now supports loading extensions from gems, see https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7788

Comment: You are indeed correct. I am actually using Razor to provision nodes now and it installs Puppet as a gem by default. But I am also using the puppetlabs-puppet module to later update Puppet and ensure the configuration is correct. Thank you for pointing this out!